# Schedule start and stop of a service at specific times

Tags: android, android-alarms

My app is doing Human Activity Recognition and notifying the user if they are not active enough. I am reading the accelerometer's data in an always running foreground service. At the moment I am trying to start and stop the service when the user is sleeping (e.g. the user sets Sleeping Hours interval 8pm - 8am) so the service should be stopped and started back on after the specified time. Currently, the following code does not work and I am not sure why. Any suggestions, please?

*Note: I know, I will make the code reuse the Calendar instance somehow, this is just for debugging purposes and get it working first.*

```
Date startSleepingHours = mUser.getStartSleepingHours();
    Date stopSleepingHours = mUser.getStopSleepingHours();
    //Create alarm manager
    AlarmManager alarmMgr0 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    Calendar cur_cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cur_cal.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());//set the current time and date for this calendar

    Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, startSleepingHours.getHours());
    cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, startSleepingHours.getMinutes());
    cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));

    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(ActiveMinutesActivity.this, IntentBroadcastedReceiver.class);
    Intent stopServiceIntent = new Intent(ActiveMinutesActivity.this, IntentBroadcastedReceiver.class);
    stopServiceIntent.putExtra("command", "STOP_SERVICE");

    PendingIntent stopServicePIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ActiveMinutesActivity.this, 0, stopServiceIntent, 0);

    PendingIntent startServicePIntent = PendingIntent.getService(ActiveMinutesActivity.this, 1, startServiceIntent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, stopServicePIntent);


    Calendar cal2 = new GregorianCalendar();
    cal2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR));
    cal2.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, stopSleepingHours.getHours());
    cal2.set(Calendar.MINUTE, stopSleepingHours.getMinutes());
    cal2.set(Calendar.SECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    cal2.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MILLISECOND));
    cal2.set(Calendar.DATE, cur_cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
    cal2.set(Calendar.MONTH, cur_cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));


    alarm.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal2.getTimeInMillis(), 60 * 1000, startServicePIntent);
```

And my Receiver class:

```
public class IntentBroadcastedReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
public IntentBroadcastedReceiver() {
}

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if(intent.getExtras() != null){
        if(intent.getExtras().get("command").equals("STOP_SERVICE")){
            context.stopService(new Intent(context, ActiveMinutesService.class));
        }else {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, ActiveMinutesService.class));
        }
    }

}
}
```

Comment: hi I am trying the same thing, did you find a solution? Or a better way

Comment: @lazy Its been a while, I cant remember how I solved it. You can have a look at my git repo https://github.com/georgikoemdzhiev/ActiveMinutes

Comment: @lazy I had a quick look and I remembered that I used that library for the scheduling https://github.com/evernote/android-job

Comment: bro thanks, this is helpful for me, thank you for taking the time to answer

Comment: @lazy no problem. Good luck with your project 